# Next js ESM required issue

Tags: next.js

[image]

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data .Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g-base\node_modules\d3-interpolate\src\index.js from D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\animate\timeline.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\animate\timeline.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\animate\timeline.js:5:24)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\abstract\canvas.js:7:18)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\index.js:17:16)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\dependents.js:6:16)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\util\scale.js:7:20)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\util\axis.js:6:15)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\facet\facet.js:7:14)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\facet\index.js:5:15)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\chart\view.js:8:15)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\chart\chart.js:8:38)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\chart\index.js:7:15)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\core.js:10:15)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\index.js:6:14)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@antv\g2plot\lib\index.js:7:31)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@ant-design\plots\lib\components\area\index.js:41:16)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@ant-design\plots\lib\index.js:21:30)
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules@ant-design\charts\lib\index.js:18:14)
at 3872 (D:\bongodeshi\frontend.next\server\pages\yourOrders.js:42:32)
at **webpack_require** (D:\bongodeshi\frontend.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
at **webpack_exec** (D:\bongodeshi\frontend.next\server\pages\yourOrders.js:2069:39)
at D:\bongodeshi\frontend.next\server\pages\yourOrders.js:2070:77
at **webpack_require**.X (D:\bongodeshi\frontend.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:108:21)
at D:\bongodeshi\frontend.next\server\pages\yourOrders.js:2070:47
at Object. (D:\bongodeshi\frontend.next\server\pages\yourOrders.js:2073:3)
at Object.requirePage (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:88:12)
at D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:37:73
at async Object.loadComponents (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:37:26)
at async D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:832:32
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

> Build error occurred
> Error: Failed to collect page data for /yourOrders
> at D:\bongodeshi\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:949:15
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
> type: 'Error'
> }
> info  - Collecting page data .

'npm run build' command not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Row now I removed the chart package from my project.